# Gradle build with Rootbeer and Pack

Tags: java, gradle

I'm Groovy/Gradle newb trying to switch build systems from ant and shell file to gradle and I'm having trouble running a Java program called Pack.jar on my code. I have tried a variety of things from Exec to JavaExec with no luck. Here is my latest failed attempt(s):

```
configurations {
    pack
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ant.importBuild('build.xml')
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}

task pack(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = configurations.pack
    workingDir = '~/Dropbox/git/BuildGraph/dist'

    main = 'pack.Main'
    args '-mainjar'
    args 'dist/buildGraph.jar'
    args '-directory'
    args '../lib'
    args '-destjar'
    args 'buildGraph-pack.jar'
}
```

I'm trying to recreate the second command line sequence:

```
$java -jar pack.jar
Usage 1: java -jar pack.jar -mainjar p2pmatrixmult.jar -libjar gson.jar -libjar hello.jar -destjar p2pmm_packed.jar
Usage 2: java -jar pack.jar -mainjar p2pmatrixmult.jar -directory jars -destjar p2pmm_packed.jar
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there're no dependencies added for `pack` configuration, is that desired configuration?

Secondly you need to pass arguments to `JavaExec` as a *list* currently there will be single argument: *'buildGraph-pack.jar'*.

```
task pack(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = configurations.pack
    workingDir = '~/Dropbox/git/BuildGraph/dist'

    main = 'pack.Main'
    args '-mainjar', 'dist/buildGraph.jar', '-directory', '../lib', '-destjar', 'buildGraph-pack.jar'
 }
```

**UPDATE**

Ok, I've downloaded the project. And.. First of all you lack basic understanding how gradle works. Please read gradle tutorial to catch the basic concepts.

**First step:**

When you run `gradle pack -s` you will se the stacktrace which has the following line (may differ):

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
>   "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java"
>   (in directory
>   "/private/tmp/BuildGraph/~/Dropbox/git/BuildGraph/dist"): error=2, No
>   such file or directory

So the first move is to change this line:

```
 workingDir = '~/Dropbox/git/BuildGraph/dist'
```

to the following:

```
workingDir = project.file('dist')
```

Again `gradle pack -s` and the error is different. Time for:

**Second step**

At the beginning it looks very unclear. The idea now is to add stream handling to get the problems - add the following lines inside `pack` task:

```
def os = new FileOutputStream(project.file('stdout'))
standardOutput = os
def es = new FileOutputStream(project.file('stderr'))
errorOutput = es
```

After viewing `stderr` it occurs that:

> Error: Could not find or load main class pack.Main

**Third step**

You indeed added the `pack` configuration but didn't define any dependency to it, `dependencies` block should be:

```
dependencies {
   pack files('pack.jar')
}
```

Again `gradle pack -s` and no exception now. But there's some content in `stderr` file:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: dist/buildGraph.jar (No such file or
>   directory)    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)  at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:131)  at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:87)   at
>   pack.Pack.addJar(Pack.java:43)    at pack.Pack.run(Pack.java:31)  at
>   pack.Main.runOnSpecifiedFiles(Main.java:71)   at
>   pack.Main.runOnDirectory(Main.java:80)    at pack.Main.run(Main.java:31)
>     at pack.Main.main(Main.java:18)

**Fourth step**

Change `workingDir` to:

```
workingDir = project.rootDir
```

Again: `gradle pack -s` and `stderr` content is:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   pack.Main.findJarFilesInDirectory(Main.java:85)   at
>   pack.Main.runOnDirectory(Main.java:79)    at pack.Main.run(Main.java:31)
>     at pack.Main.main(Main.java:18)

This is where my role finishes.

Comment: Dependencies - I was just following form in another gradle.build file I found. When I use the task above, I get: `> A problem occurred starting process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''` which is more or less what I get with most of the things I've tried. BTW: an executable java does exist on that path.

Comment: @zenlc2000, is the problem solved? Do you need any further help?

Comment: No, it exhibits the problem in my comment above and Mr. Google has not provided me an answer yet... Thank you for following up.

Comment: Any chance to try, I mean a project hosted online?

Comment: OK, I quickly put it up on GitHub: [BuildGraph](https://github.com/zenlc2000/BuildGraph)

Comment: Quickly? It's over 100MB!

Comment: Sorry - didn't realize it was that big. It's an extracted class from a larger project and I just moved all the libraries over.

Comment: Nevermind, it seems that I've helped you already at least as far as I could. If it was helpful, please accept.

Comment: I'll accept to be polite but you didn't give me anything I hadn't already tried. Thanks for trying!

Comment: I have a feeling that my configuration is more the problem than my grade so your solution would be the correct one in every other case.